# Do actually people use the expressions "Angsthase" or "Das ist ein Märchen!"?

Tags: word-usage, expression

I am studying German in Austria, Graz since few months, currently attending a A2/B1 course. Often our teachers tries to teach us some funny or commos expressions..things you would just use in spoken language and probably never write in any essay or so. 
The problem is that so often when I ask my friend (he is from Austria) if he would use these same expressions he says they sound old or ridiculous xD 
So I am wondering if any of you would ever use these expressions:

```
"Angsthase" and "Das ist ein Märchen".
```

What do you think? Are they actually used by people or not?

Comment: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Fliegende_Blaetter_85_34_b1.jpg

Comment: "Angsthase" is certainly used, though more expletive expressions may be more common (unless they forbid temselves, cf. Verodomon's workplace example). - I doubt that "Das ist ein Märchen" is used in that exact wording; you may here "etwas für ein Märchen halten" = "unwahrscheinlich/nicht glaubhaft sein" (to be unlikely/unbelievable) or "wie im Märchen"/"märchenhaft" (as romantic or free of sorrow as in a ferry tale)

Comment: First thing: Wilkommen in der Steiermark!
Second: "Angsthase" is mostly used by kids and for kids. "Das ist ein Märchen" is not used really (or at least not by people I know). You'd say "Das ist nicht wahr" or "Das ist eine Lüge".

Comment: Things like "Erzähl' keine Märchen!" are not very common, but you here it from time to time.

Comment: Märchen in der Umgangssprache kenne ich als "Märchensteuer" (Mwst.) und im IT Bereich als "User-Märchen", wenn es um unklarer Berichte von Softwareanwendern geht. "Märchen erzählen" kenne ich eher nicht.

Comment: "Sei kein solcher Angsthase!" (if you want to encourage someone to do something slightly risky) oder "Erzähl mir doch bitte keine Märchen!" (e.g., by a parent or jealous partner) sounds absolutely normal to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, hear them from time to time. "Kollege X ist ein Angsthase, der hat mal wieder den Schwanz eingezogen" oder "Es gab damals Freibier? Das halte ich für ein Märchen (often too: für ein Gerücht)". However, I believe that these expressions vary greatly from region to region and even speaker to speaker; sometimes it happens that I use something which my mother used to say and no one knows it and vice versa.

Comment: Your first example is mixing metaphors;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Das schlägt dem Fass die Krone ins Gesicht

Comment: Ihr wollt mir doch nur ein Märchen aufbinden.

Comment: Ich sehe das Problem nicht, da ich zwei getrennte Metaphern verwendet habe. Das ist bei Fass die Krone/Märchen aufbinden nicht der Fall.

Comment: Sicher ist das nicht der gleiche Fall, und selbst wenn kannst Du immer noch realistisch tatsächliche Rede wiedergegeben haben. Aber trotzdem werden da Verhaltensmuster von Hunden einem Hasen untergeschoben. Ich fand den Gedanken an einen Hasen, der den Schwanz einzieht, amüsant. Dabei hatte ich wohl auch noch fälschlich ein Kaninchen vor meinem geistigen Auge.

Comment: Mag an einer unterschiedlichen Wahrnehmung liegen: bei einem Angsthasen denke ich nicht wirklich an einen Hasen und bei Schwanz einziehen nicht wirklich an einen Hund. Ich denke daran, dass einer der "Kantinenhelden" mal wieder gekuscht hat ("Kantinenhelden" sind Leute, die in der Kantine darüber reden, was man mal alles müsse, aber dann nie den Mund aufbekommen).